# Can anyone decode this or suggest a way to decode it?

Tags: decode

I am working with a device that generates a PDF417 barcode upon receiving data. The barcode is read as below (I'm attaching 4 different example outputs by the same device). If anyone can point me in how to decode this please.

`Vsh9t+rTEIJxFIzQu/Os1BDsceAcGWe/7WZREL8fv9aTbZGuhnyZirI01z/aXzTPB2JN+4riIhrXTQINGD43WqGHzQCCGJkAsmpTByAgICAgMTE2MDIraFMHICAgIEJvc3MgUFFVSUNLU09CUAAAnwAAKgcAAAAAAAAA`

`OX0Sn6mPqJABPJtstRzmlvqjRfSXMyKqKTP5yL6JaKhetNupKiFFgRI32TDbm4MxKovt7q8s185KaNCNQGJmtaGHzQB5GJkANmpTByAgICAgMTE1OTmwZ1MHICAgIEJvc3MgUCAgIDQ0U09CPAAAdwAAXgUAAAAAAAAA`

`7SQ2PN28/K46uo9tkh2AIz8U7t8z4XVeT8FvDn2mqWd/Y6W4DC1VQCFev3yVFZPpMgotFi52zoNyyBOtRmsMo6GHzQB/GJkAiGpTByAgICAgMTE2MDECaFMHICAgIEJvc3MgUFFVSUNLU09CUAAAnwAAKgcAAAAAAAAA`

`aR9KHkCNZNtiuAE4OU5/cR/JTY3q7u2jZ4iAEFcCmu2yM4Ji6FscuWl3wTdNt0TQlzaGxovgeECgx3EjydlsQqGHzQB8GJkAX2pTByAgICAgMTE2MDDZZ1MHICAgIEJvc3MgUFFVSUNLU09CJgAASwAAXwMAAAAAAAAA`

Comment: This looks like public encryption key data, as it is in my ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. If it is, there's no "message" in it, just a key (or in this case 4 keys) which can be used to decrypt something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be Base-64 encoded data.

I've popped it through a base64 decoder and get binary data with some strings in it.
Noticeable they all have variations on     Boss PQUICKSOB as field a near the end.

Comment: I'm doing some digging and it looks like this code is produced using a combination of SHA-256 and ECC-224. Is there a way to decipher further what it contains?

Comment: ebF7ciCBXNzuY59WiBpTrNZI35xSPWF6venobSqguJQh/BDi3uflK0+jPGmU65uI5rwEmXIEO7oTq11SsIpJeYWEvwAEJZoAetEOByAgIDMzLTAwMDCa0A4HICAgICBMT0dJQyAgMjQxQVJHJwAATgAAfwMAAAAAAAAA

Comment: I think I made a mistake with pasting in the code from the other unit

Comment: ebF7ciCBXNzuY59WiBpTrNZI35xSPWF6venobSqguJQh/BDi3uflK0+jPGmU65uI5rwEmXIEO7oTq11SsIpJeYWEvwAEJZoAetEOByAgIDMzLTAwMDCa0A4HICAgICBMT0dJQyAgMjQxQVJHJwAATgAAfwMAAAAAAAAA

Comment: When I decode that code above using the Base64 decoder I get some interesting info. Below is what is decoded with Base64  y{r \cVSHߜR=azm*!+O<i뛈r;]RIy�%�z   33-0000     LOGIC  241ARG'��N���������  Follow the below links to see some of the inputs and the barcode with the data. Any ideas on what the hieroglyphs mean and if they're represented anywhere in the barcode?  [link](http://www.rlyslow.com/Work/PDF417/photo1.jpg]  [link](http://www.rlyslow.com/Work/PDF417/photo2.jpg]  [link](http://www.rlyslow.com/Work/PDF417/photo3.jpg]